# Differentiability proof of two variable function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Show that the function is differentiable: $$f\left(x,y\right) = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{y} \sin \left( xy \right) &\mbox{if } y \ne 0 \\
x & \mbox{if } y =0. \end{cases}  $$
I know the general pattern of that, but how to find a linear map in this case? How to find derivatives of this function? Appreciate your help.

Comment: First of all: partial derivatives (if they exist).

Comment: I have a problem with them as well because i have those cases, thus i am lost in the calculations.

Comment: You just differentiate each case separately. For instance, the partial derivative with respect to $x$ is
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x, y) = \cases{\frac{1}{y}\cdot y\cos(xy) & \text{if } y \neq 0\\1 & \text{if } y = 0}
$$
then you check to see whether both partial derivatives behave nicely enough.